# Advice for Building a dynamic "Advanced Search" Control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, search, dynamic, viewstate

[alt text http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/1488/advancedsearch.png](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/1488/advancedsearch.png)

I'm building an "Advanced Search" interface in an ASP.NET application.  I don't need SO to write this thing for me, but I'm stuck on a specific problem regarding dynamic controls and ViewState.   I would like some direction for how to approach this.  Here's my situation:

**Ingredients:**

- A serviceable set of API objects representing entities, fields, and searches, which handles constructing a search, generating SQL, and returning the results.  So that's all taken care of.
- ASP.NET 3.5

**Desired Interface Functionality:**

(1) On initial page load, the interface gets a preconfigured Search object with a set of SearchCriterion objects.  It binds them into a set of controls (see image above.)

- Some search items are simpler, like:

  Field (DropDownList) | Operator (DropDownList) | Value (TextBox)
- Search Criterion controls for some field types have important information stored in viewstate, like:

  Field (DropDownList) | Operator (DropDownList) | Value (DropDownList)  where the "Value" dropdownlist is populated by a database query.
- Some fields are lookups to other Entities, which causes a chain of field selectors, like:

  Field (DropDownList) Field (DropDownList) | Operator (DropDownList) | Value

(2) The user modifies the search by:

- Adding and Removing search criteria by clicking respective buttons
- Configuring existing criteria by changing the Field, Operator, or Value.  Changes to Field or Operator will require the control to reconfigure itself by changing the available operators, changing the "Value" input control to a different type, or adding/removing DropDownLists from the "Fields" section if Lookup-type fields are selected/unselected.

(3) Finally, the user hits "Search" to see their results.

**The Problem:**

As you probably already know if you're answering this question, controls added dynamically to the page disappear on postback.  I've created a UserControl that manipulates the control collection and neatly accomplishes step (1) above as you can see in the attached image.  (I'm not concerned about style at this point, obviously.)

However on Postback, the controls are all gone, and my Search API object is gone.  If I could get the dynamically generated control collection to just play nice and stick in ViewState, I could examine the controls on postback, rebuild the Search object, then handle control events neatly.

**Possible Solutions**

- I could make the Search object serializable and store it in viewstate.  Then on page load I could grab it and reconstruct the control collection at page load time.  However I'm not sure if this would play nicely with controls raising events, and what happens to the viewstate of Drop-down lists that contain data from the database - could I get it back?  It's highly undesirable for me to have to re-query the database on every postback.
- I could develop a custom server control ([see this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx)) for this kind of thing... but that is a new topic for me and would involve some learning, plus I'm not totally sure if a custom server control would work any more nicely with non-fixed control collections.  Anybody know about that?
- I was thinking that I might be able to accomplish this using databound controls - for example I could bind my criterion collection to a repeater which has a fixed control collection (maybe hide the non-used "value" controls, use an inner repeater for the "Field" drop-down lists).  Then all the information would stay in ViewState... right?
- Any new ideas would be greatly appreciated.

thanks for your help.
b.Fandango

Comment: This is a great post, and I'm trying to build almost the exact same kind of search page.  Would you mind sharing any examples of your initial work, namely creating, "A serviceable set of API objects representing entities, fields, and searches, which handles constructing a search, generating SQL, and returning the results."  If you have any links, or info to share, it would be very helpful, just concerned, i don't want to reinvent the wheel if there are already libs/frameworks out there doing this sort of thing.  Thanks, for the great post!

Comment: russds, I work on a medium-size enterprise software package that has its own metadata (entities & fields) and search implementations.  I'm not able to share any of my employer's source code with you although I'm sure they wouldn't mind if I wrote about the design and implementation of that part of the system.  However I think there are a number of "business object" base class libraries and such out there that can give you these types of features.  I'll see what I can find for you but I recommend a quick google on your side too.

Comment: Thanks Barry.  I have done some googling, but not exactly what to google, I've tried things like "Dynamic Search UI", and "asp.net advanced search", nothing concrete comes up.  Your description is exactly what I'm looking for, what kinds of terms would I search for?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been coding for about a day and I got this working beautifully using the third option I suggested in my question - old-school databound controls.  Actually I only thought of the idea when I was forced to write out the question in detail - doesn't that just happen to you all the time?

I put my SearchCriterionControl into an asp:Repeater and bound it to my object collection.  For the Field Chooser I put an asp:DropDownList inside a nested asp:Repeater and bound the Field array to that.  Everything works beautifully, keeps state, actually required very little code.  So I never had to dynamically add controls to the page, thank goodness.

Thanks for your suggestions, Ender, Matt and andrewWinn.

Answer (score 2):

Since no one else has taken a stab at this for 2 hours, I'll throw my hat in the ring with a solution that does not rely on viewstate at all (or the ASP.NET model of postbacks).

What if you grabbed all the input values with jQuery and instead of doing a post-back did a post against the page (or a new results.aspx page)?  Or, you could make the entire thing asyncrhonous and do an Ajax request against a web method, get fed the results, and populate on the client side as needed?

The unfortunate thing here is you have to reconstruct which type of controls were used to figure construct your search query since that data wont be passed with the viewstate.  But I imagine you were already going to have to do some kind of translation of your input data into a query form anyway.

Read [here](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) for more information about using jQuery to hit an ASP.NET page method.  Remember - page methods must be static (it's an easy oversight).

I'm not sure what you're doing server side to construct your query - but I would *highly* recommend LINQ.  I did a similar "advanced search" function previously, and after a few different attempts found that LINQ was a wonderful tool for this problem, regardless of whether I was hitting SQL with LINQtoSQL or just hitting an in-memory collection of objects.

This worked so well because 1) LINQ is deferred execution and 2) A LINQ query returns another queryable object.  The implication here is that you can chain your LINQ queries together as you construct them from your input, instead of having to do a single massive clause translation to SQL or whatever backstore you are using (one of my attempts was constructing SQL clauses with strings, but still passing input data via SQLParameters for SQL injection protection - it was messy and complicated when hand crafted LINQ was orders of magnitude easier to understand and implement).

For example:

```
List<string> data; // or perhaps your a DB Context for LINQtoSQL?

var query = data.Where(item => item.contains("foo"));

if( {user supplies length search option} )
    query = query.Where(item => item.Length < 5);

// etc, etc.

// LINQ doesn't do anything until the query is iterated, at which point
// it will construct the SQL statement without you worrying about details or parameter binding
foreach(string value in query)
    ; // do something with the results
```

Because of deferred execution and the queryable return type, you can concatenate LINQ queries to this expression all day long and let it worry about the implementation details (such as converting to a SQL query) at execution time.

Comment: Commenting on my own answer here because this is not relevant to the question/answer, and is highly opinionated - but this is one of the reasons I dropped ASP.NET in favor of ASP.NET MVC.  The HTTP protocol is not stateful, and the ASP.NET model of viewstate is really just a monkey-patch to get state on a web application.  And as such, you encounter these sorts of problems.  While there might be a true ASP.NET/postback solution, the complexity involved begins to outweigh the benefits.  After all, you're just trying to send data back to the server!  Should be easy as pie.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain all this Matt.  While it does dodge my specific problem with ViewState, it does so by discarding the whole approach and introducing a number of new challenges.  This is a bit of an "everything looks like a nail when all you have is a hammer" solution - something I see on SO a lot with jQuery for some reason.

Comment: Thanks also for the advice about the API and DB side, I know it's not related to the question but I appreciate hearing another point of view on the subject.

Comment: @barry, understandable.  That's why I held off until I noticed after 2 hours you still didn't have any answers.  Obviously, there are multiple ways to accomplish the same goal, some better than others, and that varies by person even.  As for jQuery - its popoluar in many communities online, but particularly so in .NET because Microsoft is in fact shipping it as part of VS2008.  You'll notice if you create a new web project (at least I did in ASP.NET MVC) that the javascript folder has jQuery in it already.

Comment: I know we're getting off-topic Matt, but that's pretty awesome eh?  For MS to pluck a best-of-breed JS framework from the wild regardless of its licensing and incorporate it into something like the MVC product is really amazing to see.

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide you with the exact steps that you will need to do, but I HIGHLY suggest looking into asp.net page life cycle.  I created a user control as a DLL one time.  I had to capture postback data at specific steps in the lifecycle and recreate and rebind the data at other steps.  Additionally thinkgs like viewstate are only available at certain points also.  I know that I had to override On_init, On_prerender and some other methods.

Sorry I couldn't be more help, but I don't have the code with me (its with an old employer).  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding controls to the controls tree dynamically, you need to add them on postpack as well. Just call the method that builds the control on Page_Load or Page_Init and the controls should stay on the page on postback.